# How to correct deprecated preference methods?

Tags: java, android

I have those three scratched in my eclipse and it's written they are deprecated. English is not my mother tongue and I can't really get what they mean and how I can correct it. Any hints?

> ```
>     preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager(); ...
>     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
>     Preference aboutItem = findPreference("about");
> ```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706294/752320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to deal with it is to use [UnifiedPreference](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference) library. another way is to write your own fragment/activity that stores and retrieves preferences.